# Newline inserted when concatenating strings

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a package that deletes old elements from some tables.
This package runs within a batch and writes its result in a logfile.
The problem is that for some reason, a newline is inserted when concatening some strings.

This is the general log-procedure:

```
-- *****************************************************************************
-- This procedure logs the specified message
-- *****************************************************************************
PROCEDURE LogMessage
(
  p_message IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN

  -- Log message
  dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || ' ' || p_message);

END LogMessage;
```

This is the procedure that creates the problems:

```
-- *****************************************************************************
-- This procedure logs the specified message
-- *****************************************************************************
PROCEDURE LogPurgeResult
(
  p_table   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_records IN NUMBER
)
IS
  v_last_analyzed VARCHAR2(20);
  v_num_rows      NUMBER;
  v_message       VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN

  -- Determine number of records within table
  SELECT TO_CHAR(last_analyzed, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         num_rows
    INTO v_last_analyzed,
         v_num_rows
    FROM user_tables
   WHERE table_name = UPPER(p_table);

  -- Compose message
  v_message := 'Deleted ' || TO_CHAR(p_records) || ' records from ' || p_table;
  IF (v_last_analyzed IS NOT NULL) THEN
    v_message := v_message || '. Number of records at ' || v_last_analyzed || ' --> ' || TO_CHAR(v_num_rows);
  END IF;

  -- Log message
  LogMessage(v_message);

END LogPurgeResult;
```

The output I get is:

```
2016-09-02 09:37:38 Deleted 12 records from MONITORING_STATUS. Number of records at
2016-08-24 02:01:29 --> 1960
```

For some reason, a newline is inserted after the string `Number of records at`

If I change the string `Number of records at` into `Records at`, the newline is inserted after the date:

```
2016-09-02 09:48:47 Deleted 0 records from MONITORING_STATUS. Records at 2016-06-14
02:01:29 --> 1960
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: did you do `set linesize` in the script that outputs the logfile? [This question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line) may help

Comment: @vkp: you're a genious!! Indeed, I do set the linesize. I enlarged it and now it's working.